# What is the "Void" ball?

Tags: destiny

There are two balls in the Tower in Destiny; a soccer ball, and a "Void" ball.

What exactly is the "Void" ball? My assumption is that it's a bug that Bungie has somehow overlooked, due to it's misplaced appearance and physics. it also seems... low-quality compared to the rest of the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just meant to be a toy to be "social" with in the tower.

I agree that it looks very low poly compared to the other ball. I suspect (but haven't been able to confirm yet) that it's from early development to test the in-game collisions.

Comment: It was in the BETA as well, it really is just a toy. People just bounce it around and push it off the edge...and some like me...sit on it and float like a maniac off the edge.

Comment: I take it to what I call the Ball Pit by the speaker. Only having two balls in it doesn't make it much of a pit though.

Comment: You can't beat a 10 player ballfest! Til it gets stuck :\